# How to share app

Tags: iphone, share

I'm developing an app. I'm going to publish to an app store. But client needs to share this app with friends. I have a button to share my app. How to share the app? I read some doc they mentioned, use `[[UIApplication SharedApplication] openURL:@" url"]`. I don't have my app URL. Because I didn't submit the app. Is it possible to share my app?

Comment: Before your application is published in the app store, you can only share the app with them by obtaining their device UUID, and creating a provisioning profile for them in the member center.

Comment: You are correct. Here requirement is i have button, when click the button i need to share this app to facebook or email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what the URL of your application will be *before* it has been submitted/approved, Apple provides a shorthand URL you can use, of the form:

http://itunes.com/apps/appname

For example:

http://itunes.com/apps/AngryBirds

If you want the specific URL with the application ID, you could submit v1.0.0 without the "Share" link, then immediately submit a 1.0.1 update with the link included.

Comment: Already i submit the version 1.0 to appstore. It approved. Im going to submit 1.0.1 next version. Shall i use 1.0 version url?

Comment: Yes, the URL will not change between versions, it will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Url can be generated via app id. Its the best way to do it coz if app name changes, url could change. But app id wont change.

You can get your app id on itunesConnect.apple.com or via itunes. 
//https://itunes.apple.com/app/id_hereisyourappID
Let see how to do the sharing.

I will show you 4 ways to share your link. Via Facebook, Twitter, Mail and SMS.

For Facebook and Twitter.
Add Accounts and Social framework. And in your header import.

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

when you want to share link use the following code

```
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];//for twitter use SLServiceTypeTwitter

[mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789"]];
[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Lets do it with mail  add MessageUI framework and import

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

And the delegate `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

in your code

```
MFMailComposeViewController* mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[mailComposer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789" isHTML:NO];
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And add delegate method

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
 {
  [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

You can create html content for mail body.

Lets share it via SMS

Add delegate `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
   if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {              
       controller.body = @"https://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789";
       controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

And add delegate method.

```
-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have version 1.0 app already have in appstore. Im going to update only. So i can use previous version url.

Comment: Sure just copy from itunes it wont change.